# Zrok tunnel randomly stop working and redirects to the 404 zrok not found page

Tags: tunnel

I'm using a Zrok reserved tunnel to expose my locally hosted website to the internet because I do not currently have access to port forwarding from my router. I started the tunnel and It was working fine until the next morning when It just randomly stopped redirecting to the website

I did not expect the tunnel to randomly disconnect like that.